# Fit a longtable to page width

Tags: longtable

I'm a beginner with LaTeX, so excuse me if the solution might be obvius for someone but I am still learning.
I have a problem with a longtable. It doesn't fit the page width, and I already tried some options that other people described in other posts like using a small font, try longtabu, and I don't want a landscape table.
Thank you very much.
This is the code:

````
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    letterpaper,
    oneside]
\RequirePackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=40mm,rmargin=25mm}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l>|ll}
\cline{1-5}
\centering
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tripulante de\\  cabina\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuario Frecuente por\\  trabajo\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuario frecuente por\\  turismo\end{tabular} & Agente de viajes &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{7}{c}%
{{\bfseries Tabla \thetable\ continuación de la página anterior}} \\
\cline{1-5}
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tripulante de\\  cabina\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuario Frecuente por\\  trabajo\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuario frecuente por\\  turismo\end{tabular} & Agente de viajes &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\endhead
%
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Proceso de \\ compra/factores\\ más importantes\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La compra del pasaje está \\ determinada por el lugar de\\ destino, y hecha por agencia \\ de viajes asociada a empresa.\\ Factor más importante: \\ Flexibilidad para cambios.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Primero selecciona el lugar \\ de destino, luego se guía por \\ el precio. Trata de disminuir \\ el tiempo de vuelo, buscando\\ la menor cantidad de escalas\\ posibles.\end{tabular} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Proceso de \\ compra y factor \\ más importante \\ en nueva normalidad\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}El factor más importante al \\ momento de comprar seguirá\\ siendo la flexibilidad del\\ pasaje.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Depende de las aerolíneas \\ que queden, pero el factor \\ más importante seguirá\\ siendo el precio.\end{tabular} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Consumo de \\ productos durante\\  el vuelo\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usualmente come antes de \\ abordar, y durante el\\ vuelo solo come lo que\\ ya está incluido en el pasaje \\ (en caso de viajes largos).\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No suele consumir\\ productos durante el vuelo, \\ aparte de los que incluye \\ el pasaje.\end{tabular} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Consultas más\\ habituales dentro \\ del avión y antes \\ del vuelo\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Consultas generales, acerca \\ del tiempo de vuelo, cantidad \\ de pasajeros, preguntas\\ acerca del lugar de \\ destino, etc.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}En su opinión, la información\\ necesaria esta toda disponible\\ online, además sumado a su\\ experiencia no considera \\ necesaria las consultas \\ durante el vuelo\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No hace preguntas ya \\ que no lo considera \\ necesario, debido a la \\ frecuencia con que viaja \\ ya sabe la mayoría \\ de las cosas.\end{tabular} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Posibles consultas \\ en situación de \\ nueva normalidad.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Preguntas relacionadas con \\ la sanitización del avión, \\ distanciamiento social, uso \\ de mascarillas, y regulación \\ sanitaria en el país de destino.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Dudas acerca del proceso de\\ sanitización del avión, sobre \\ el manejo de alimentos y \\ bebidas a bordo. \\ Funcionamiento del\\ sistema de ventilación del \\ avión.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Preguntas acerca de si \\ los cambios requeridos \\ en lo sanitario han sido \\ adoptados de forma \\ correcta.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Preguntas acerca de si\\ el vuelo es seguro, si el\\ avión estará sanitizado, \\ si el personal tendrá \\ barreras de contacto \\ adecuadas.\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Disposición a viajar\\ en nueva normalidad\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La gente en general está \\ asustada de volar, o tomar\\ cualquier riesgo, aunque\\ siempre existirán pasajeros\\ que viajaran bajo\\ cualquier condición.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La disposición a viajar será \\ la misma por la naturaleza\\ de su trabajo. No cree que\\ el avión contagie más o\\ menos que un microbús\\ u otro medio de transporte.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sería la misma que antes\\ de la pandemia, solo hay\\ que adaptarse a las\\ nuevas modalidades.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La gente tendrá menos \\ disposición a viajar, la \\ mayoría ya reagendo su \\ viaje para el próximo \\ año, desde Julio incluso.\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Disposición a aceptar \\ cambios o atrasos en\\ el vuelo y \\ compensaciones\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Debe existir disposición a \\ cambios o fallas en la entrega \\ de servicios que no dependan\\ de ellos, así como una \\ compensación en caso\\ contrario.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La disposición sería la misma \\ que antes de la pandemia, la \\ cual es baja, a menos que sea\\ un caso muy especial. La \\ compensación que espera es\\ que la aerolínea la lleve a\\ destino como sea.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La gente generalmente no \\ entiende el efecto global \\ de la pandemia, alrededor \\ del 70\%, y exigirían \\ compensaciones respectivas\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Medidas o tipos de \\ protocolos que son \\ deseables o se podrían \\ esperar de las aerolíneas \\ en la nueva normalidad\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Protocolos de comportamiento\\ de las personas dentro del \\ avión, de sanitizado, uso de \\ mascarillas, además de \\ campaña de educación a\\ la gente.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Medidas similares a las \\ esperables de cualquier lugar\\ donde se aglomere gente, \\ por ejemplo, mejoras en el \\ filtrado de aire, sanitización \\ más profunda de sus servicios\\ higiénicos, y limpieza \\ profunda durante stop over.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No espera ninguna medida \\ en específico, pero sí que\\ sean acordes a las \\ recomendaciones de la \\ autoridad.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Se necesitan campañas de \\ educación para la gente, ya \\ que esta es muy porfiada en \\ su comportamiento.\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Disposición de los \\ pasajeros a volver a \\ usar las mismas \\ aerolíneas que usaban \\ antes o nuevas que \\ surjan en nueva\\ normalidad.\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Esta dispuesto a usar las \\ aerolíneas que estén \\ disponibles y que ofrezcan \\ un mejor servicio en cuanto \\ a flexibilidad.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No necesariamente iría por \\ las mismas aerolíneas, si no\\ por las que ofrezcan \\ mejores fechas y precios.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La gente volverá a las \\ mismas aerolíneas, sobre\\ todo en el contexto de\\ la baja oferta de aerolíneas\\ distintas a nivel nacional.\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Culpabilidad de las\\  aerolíneas en la \\ propagación del virus.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No atribuye culpabilidad \\ a las aerolíneas ya que \\ están son medio más\\ de transporte existente.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La propagación del virus es\\ una realidad inherente a los\\ medios de transporte, por \\ lo que no les atribuye\\ culpabilidad específica a las\\  aerolíneas.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No, porque existe un gran \\ desconocimiento de cómo\\ funciona el virus y se va \\ aprendiendo sobre la marcha,\\ y nadie anda contagiando\\ voluntariamente.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Mas que a las aerolíneas en\\ sí, atribuye culpabilidad a\\ los controles fronterizos o\\ sanitarios, que podrían \\ haber funcionado de mejor\\ manera y así controlado \\ mejor la pandemia.\end{tabular} &  &  \\ \cline{1-5}
\end{longtable}```
````

Comment: Hey @Pablo, welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please post a complete example, so others can see your document class, page size and used fonts to support you further?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Wich documentclass do you use? Also do you use the `geometry` package to change the margin size? If so, please include this infromation into your question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer guys. I think i added what you asked for. Im using a template so its kinda confusing for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you declare 7 columns?. The last two are empty. And whet are you meaning with the ` >|ll`  in the table preamble?

Comment: Yea someone noticed that too and he fixed it, thanks tho.

Answer (score 2):

I propose this code, with a slightly different layout, loading the `xltabular` package, which combines tabularx (forthe pagewidth) and longtable. It results in a simpler code. You also have the possibility to enlarge locally the line width (which I didn't do), with the `adjustwidth`  environment, from `changepage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,    letterpaper,    oneside, spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, margin=25mm, lmargin=40mm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\newcommand\nl{\newline}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
\hline
 & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Usuario frecuente }} & \\[1ex]
 & \thead{ Tripulante \\ de cabina} & \thead{ por trabajo} & \thead{ por turismo} & \thead{ Agente \\de viajes} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{5}{c}%7
{{\bfseries Tabla \thetable\ continuación de la página anterior}} \\[1.5ex]
\hline
 & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Usuario frecuente }} & \\[1ex]
 & \thead{Tripulante \\ de cabina} & \thead{por trabajo} & \thead{por turismo} & \thead{Agente \\de viajes} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
Proceso de compra/factores más importantes & & La compra del pasaje está determinada por el lugar de destino, y hecha por agencia de viajes asociada a empresa.\nl Factor más importante: \nl Flexibilidad para cambios. & Primero selecciona el lugar de destino, luego se guía por el precio. Trata de disminuir el tiempo de vuelo, buscando la menor cantidad de escalas posibles. & \\
\hline
Proceso de compra y factor más importante en nueva normalidad & & El factor más importante al momento de comprar seguirá siendo la flexibilidad del pasaje. & Depende de las aerolíneas que queden, pero el factor más importante seguirá siendo el precio. & \\
\hline
Consumo de productos durante el vuelo & & Usualmente come antes de abordar, y durante el vuelo solo come lo que ya está incluido en el pasaje (en caso de viajes largos). & No suele consumir productos durante el vuelo, aparte de los que incluye el pasaje. & \\
\hline
 Consultas más habituales dentro del avión y antes del vuelo & Consultas generales, acerca del tiempo de vuelo, cantidad de pasajeros, preguntas acerca del lugar de destino, etc & En su opinión, la información necesaria esta toda disponible online, además sumado a su experiencia no considera necesaria las consultas durante el vuelo & No hace preguntas ya que no lo considera necesario, debido a la frecuencia con que viaja ya sabe la mayoría de las cosas. & \\
 \hline
Posibles consultas en situación de nueva normalidad & Preguntas relacionadas con la sanitización del avión, distanciamiento social, uso de mascarillas, y regulación sanitaria en el país de destino. & Dudas acerca del proceso de sanitización del avión, sobre el manejo de alimentos y bebidas a bordo. Funcionamiento de sistema de ventilación del avión. & Preguntas acerca de si los cambios requeridos en lo sanitario han sido adoptados de forma correcta. & Preguntas acerca de si el vuelo es seguro, si el avión estará sanitizado, si el personal tendrá barreras de contacto adecuadas. \\
\hline
 Disposición a viajar en nueva normalidad & La gente en general está asustada de volar, o tomar cualquier riesgo, aunque siempre existirán pasajeros que viajaran bajo cualquier condición. & La disposición a viajar será \ la misma por la naturaleza de su trabajo. No cree que el avión contagie más o menos que un microbús u otro medio de transporte. & Sería la misma que antes de la pandemia, solo hay que adaptarse a las nuevas modalidades & La gente tendrá menos disposición a viajar, la mayoría ya reagendo su viaje para el próximo año, desde Julio incluso. \\
 \hline
Disposición a aceptar cambios o atrasos en el vuelo y compensaciones & & Debe existir disposición a cambios o fallas en la entrega de servicios que no dependan de ellos, así como una compensación en caso contrario. & La disposición sería la misma que antes de la pandemia, la cual es baja, a menos que sea un caso muy especial. La compensación que espera es que la aerolínea la lleve a destino como sea. & La gente generalmente no entiende el efecto global de la pandemia, alrededor del 70\%, y exigirían compensaciones respectivas \\
\hline
Medidas o tipos de protocolos que son deseables o se podrían esperar de las aerolíneas en la nueva normalidad & Protocolos de comportamiento de las personas dentro del avión, de sanitizado, uso de mascarillas, además de campaña de educación a la gente. & Medidas similares a las esperables de cualquier lugar donde se aglomere gente, por ejemplo, mejoras en el filtrado de aire, sanitización más profunda de sus servicios higiénicos, y limpieza profunda durante stop over. & No espera ninguna medida en específico, pero sí que sean acordes a las recomendaciones de la autoridad. & Se necesitan campañas de educación para la gente, ya que esta es muy porfiada en su comportamiento. \\
\hline
Disposición de los pasajeros a volver a usar las mismas aerolíneas que usaban antes o nuevas que surjan en nueva normalidad. & & Esta dispuesto a usar las aerolíneas que estén disponibles y que ofrezcan un mejor servicio en cuanto a flexibilidad. & No necesariamente iría por las mismas aerolíneas, si no por las que ofrezcan mejores fechas y precios. & La gente volverá a las mismas aerolíneas, sobre todo en el contexto de la baja oferta de aerolíneas distintas a nivel nacional. \\
\hline
Culpabilidad de las aerolíneas en la propagación del virus. & No atribuye culpabilidad a las aerolíneas ya que están son medio más de transporte existente. & La propagación del virus es una realidad inherente a los medios de transporte, por lo que no les atribuye culpabilidad específica a las aerolíneas. & No, porque existe un gran desconocimiento de cómo funciona el virus y se va aprendiendo sobre la marcha, y nadie anda contagiando voluntariamente. & Mas que a las aerolíneas en sí, atribuye culpabilidad a los controles fronterizos o sanitarios, que podrían haber funcionado de mejor manera y así controlado mejor la pandemia. \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first quick version using some landscape page in order to increase the column widths and hopefully make the text in the cells more readable.

In comparison to the original code, I have removed all nester `tabular` environments and manual linebreaks inside of them. Instead I used `p` type columns and automatic linebreaks. I have also removed the two unneccessary columns (you decared 7 but only need 5) as well as replaced all `\cline{1-5}` with `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    letterpaper,
    oneside]{article}
    
\RequirePackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=40mm,rmargin=25mm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\caption{caption text}\\
\hline
\centering
 & Tripulante de cabina 
    & Usuario Frecuente por  trabajo 
      & Usuario frecuente por turismo 
        & Agente de viajes 
           \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{continuación de la página anterior}
\\ \hline
 & Tripulante de cabina 
    & Usuario Frecuente por  trabajo 
      & Usuario frecuente por turismo 
        & Agente de viajes 
          \\ \hline
\endhead
%
Proceso de compra/factores más importantes 
  &  
    & La compra del pasaje está  determinada por el lugar de destino, y hecha por agencia  de viajes asociada a empresa. Factor más importante:  Flexibilidad para cambios.
       & Primero selecciona el lugar  de destino, luego se guía por el precio. Trata de disminuir  el tiempo de vuelo, buscando la menor cantidad de escalas posibles.
          &   \\ \hline
Proceso de compra y factor más importante en nueva normalidad
  &  
    & El factor más importante al  momento de comprar seguirá siendo la flexibilidad del pasaje. 
      & Depende de las aerolíneas  que queden, pero el factor  más importante seguirá siendo el precio. 
        &  \\ \hline
Consumo de  productos durante  el vuelo 
  &  
    & Usualmente come antes de  abordar, y durante el vuelo solo come lo que ya está incluido en el pasaje  (en caso de viajes largos). 
      & No suele consumir productos durante el vuelo,  aparte de los que incluye  el pasaje. 
        & \\ \hline
Consultas más habituales dentro  del avión y antes  del vuelo 
  & Consultas generales, acerca  del tiempo de vuelo, cantidad  de pasajeros, preguntas acerca del lugar de  destino, etc. 
    & En su opinión, la información necesaria esta toda disponible online, además sumado a su experiencia no considera  necesaria las consultas  durante el vuelo 
      & No hace preguntas ya  que no lo considera  necesario, debido a la  frecuencia con que viaja  ya sabe la mayoría  de las cosas. 
        &   \\ \hline
Posibles consultas  en situación de  nueva normalidad. 
  & Preguntas relacionadas con  la sanitización del avión,  distanciamiento social, uso  de mascarillas, y regulación  sanitaria en el país de destino. 
    & Dudas acerca del proceso de sanitización del avión, sobre  el manejo de alimentos y  bebidas a bordo.  Funcionamiento del sistema de ventilación del  avión. 
      & Preguntas acerca de si  los cambios requeridos  en lo sanitario han sido  adoptados de forma  correcta. 
        & Preguntas acerca de si el vuelo es seguro, si el avión estará sanitizado,  si el personal tendrá  barreras de contacto  adecuadas. 
            \\ \hline
Disposición a viajar  en nueva normalidad 
  & La gente en general está   asustada de volar, o tomar  cualquier riesgo, aunque  siempre existirán pasajeros  que viajaran bajo  cualquier condición. 
    & La disposición a viajar será   la misma por la naturaleza  de su trabajo. No cree que  el avión contagie más o  menos que un microbús  u otro medio de transporte. 
      & Sería la misma que antes  de la pandemia, solo hay  que adaptarse a las  nuevas modalidades. 
        & La gente tendrá menos   disposición a viajar, la   mayoría ya reagendo su   viaje para el próximo   año, desde Julio incluso. 
            \\ \hline
Disposición a aceptar   cambios o atrasos en  el vuelo y   compensaciones 
  &  
    & Debe existir disposición a   cambios o fallas en la entrega   de servicios que no dependan  de ellos, así como una   compensación en caso  contrario. 
      & La disposición sería la misma   que antes de la pandemia, la   cual es baja, a menos que sea  un caso muy especial. La   compensación que espera es  que la aerolínea la lleve a  destino como sea. 
        & La gente generalmente no   entiende el efecto global   de la pandemia, alrededor   del 70\%, y exigirían   compensaciones respectivas 
            \\ \hline
Medidas o tipos de   protocolos que son   deseables o se podrían   esperar de las aerolíneas   en la nueva normalidad 
  & Protocolos de comportamiento  de las personas dentro del   avión, de sanitizado, uso de   mascarillas, además de   campaña de educación a  la gente. 
    & Medidas similares a las   esperables de cualquier lugar  donde se aglomere gente,   por ejemplo, mejoras en el   filtrado de aire, sanitización   más profunda de sus servicios  higiénicos, y limpieza   profunda durante stop over. 
      & No espera ninguna medida   en específico, pero sí que  sean acordes a las   recomendaciones de la   autoridad.  
        & Se necesitan campañas de   educación para la gente, ya   que esta es muy porfiada en   su comportamiento. 
            \\ \hline
Disposición de los   pasajeros a volver a   usar las mismas   aerolíneas que usaban   antes o nuevas que   surjan en nueva  normalidad. 
  &  
    & Esta dispuesto a usar las   aerolíneas que estén   disponibles y que ofrezcan   un mejor servicio en cuanto   a flexibilidad. 
      & No necesariamente iría por   las mismas aerolíneas, si no  por las que ofrezcan   mejores fechas y precios. 
        & La gente volverá a las   mismas aerolíneas, sobre  todo en el contexto de  la baja oferta de aerolíneas  distintas a nivel nacional. 
           \\ \hline
Culpabilidad de las   aerolíneas en la   propagación del virus. 
  & No atribuye culpabilidad   a las aerolíneas ya que   están son medio más  de transporte existente. 
     & La propagación del virus es  una realidad inherente a los  medios de transporte, por   lo que no les atribuye  culpabilidad específica a las   aerolíneas. 
       & No, porque existe un gran   desconocimiento de cómo  funciona el virus y se va   aprendiendo sobre la marcha,  y nadie anda contagiando  voluntariamente. 
         & Mas que a las aerolíneas en  sí, atribuye culpabilidad a  los controles fronterizos o  sanitarios, que podrían   haber funcionado de mejor  manera y así controlado   mejor la pandemia. 
            \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I sill don't understand what you did lol but works for me but I really apprecciate it  :) .

Comment: @PabloSalgado: If you have a question about a specific part of the code I used, please feel free to ask.